# SOX detecting silence when reading mp3 from url

Tags: audio, streaming, sox

I setup a nice utility to log and record scanner radio traffic and then remove silence using SOX.  To record continuously I keep calling SOX with silence detection:

```
function dosox() {
/usr/bin/sox -t alsa -D "plughw:2,0" $DATE.wav silence 1 0.1 2% 1 1.0 2%
 dosox  
}
dosox
```

This works very well for ALSA sound devices.  However I now would like to get the stream from a url.  I use the URL source like:

```
function dosox() {
/usr/bin/sox -t mp3 $CHAN_URL $DATE.wav silence 1 1.0 2% 1 2.0 2%   
 dosox  
}
dosox
```

**With the stream SOX seems to generate many audio output files quickly.  Many of these files are near duplicates. (They contain the same transmission).  I think SOX is out running the stream cache and considering this the end of the file, then terminating.**  Then when SOX is called the next time it grabs the same stream which apparently can be of audio which was already streamed.

Assuming this is what is going on, I am looking for an easy way to have SOX exit on actual silence on the stream, but wait a bit when it thinks it got to the end of the stream for more audio.  Things I tried:

-Used mplayer to stream to a fifo and read that in with SOX.

-Tried to adjust the silence settings of the SOX silence effect.

[Here is an example stream](http://audio5.broadcastify.com/838989288)

Comment: I don't know about the silence effect, but the voice activity detection effect (vad) seems to work.

Comment: SOX continues to impress me with its seemingly endless features - didn't even know vad existed, thanks!

Comment: @Thor , could you provide an example? There is not much in the way of vad examples.  I am also reading vad can be used to start recording,  but not end it.

Comment: I fetched a bit of the stream to `out.mp3` and played it back with: `play  out.mp3 vad` and `play out.mp3 norm vad`.